# python and sqlite3, check if I can use fts5 extension?

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search, fts5

I recently found out that [FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) extension has been released.
What is the best way to check if my application can use it on users system?
Just python3 version check, or sqlite3.sqlite_version check according to [release page](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)?? Or something else?

Comment: The answer does not belong into the question but into an answer (you can answer your own question). If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**/ this was previously edit of the OP post, but I moved it down here to keep the question clear**

so this feels like it could work, found it in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060010/using-sqlites-fts3-4-with-python-3/30063441)

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('pragma compile_options;')
available_pragmas = cur.fetchall()
con.close()

print(available_pragmas)

if ('ENABLE_FTS5',) in available_pragmas:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

But what is strange is that I run it in a few virtual machines, and none had fts4 enabled, yet I used it happily like nothing... maybe its fts3/fts4 being rather the same, or maybe its just all wrong.

**/edit**
from the documentation

> Note that enabling FTS3 also makes FTS4 available. There is not a separate SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 compile-time option. A build of SQLite either supports both FTS3 and FTS4 or it supports neither.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation you link to mentions that FTS5 is disabled by default. Did you enable it when compiling SQLite?

One quick way to know is to use the [`peewee` ORM](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#FTS5Model):

```
from playhouse.sqlite_ext import FTS5Model
FTS5Model.fts5_installed()
```

The above will return `True` if you can use FTS5. You can install `peewee` with `pip install peewee`.

You could also use the `apsw` wrapper, which [includes FTS5 by default since version 3.11.0-r1](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/changes.html?highlight=fts5#id1). See the [build instructions](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/build.html) and use the `--enable-all-extensions` flag. The `apsw` wrapper uses the [amalgamation](https://sqlite.org/amalgamation.html).

**EDIT:**
Here is the code from the [`peewee` source](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/playhouse/sqlite_ext.py) demonstrating how this is done:

```
def fts5_installed(cls):
    if sqlite3.sqlite_version_info[:3] < FTS5_MIN_VERSION:
        return False

    # Test in-memory DB to determine if the FTS5 extension is installed.
    tmp_db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    try:
        tmp_db.execute('CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts5test USING fts5 (data);')
    except:
        try:
            sqlite3.enable_load_extension(True)
            sqlite3.load_extension('fts5')
        except:
            return False
        else:
            cls._meta.database.load_extension('fts5')
    finally:
        tmp_db.close()

    return True
```

Comment: Bringing frameworks I dont use in to this for just checking seems rather not ideal.

Comment: @DoTheEvo, Yeah, but you could read the [peewee source](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/playhouse/sqlite_ext.py) for yourself and see how it's done! The function is just 19 lines; you don't need to actually use `peewee`, just copy the code you need.

Comment: [Disclosure: I am the apsw author]  There is no 100% certain way to find out if the extension is present other than by trying to use it.  The extension could be compiled as part of SQLite or separately loadable.  There is no guarantee either that 'fts5' is the one you are expecting.  In any event the code above is the most robust way to check.