# Upgrade Python's sqlite3 on Debian

Tags: python, sqlite, pip, debian

I'm using Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2 on my Debian, and I'm usually using module `sqlite3` without any problem.

I [compiled a Sqlite extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815419/1422096) `spellfix`, I get this error when loading it:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: ./spellfix.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_malloc64

I think it might be because the `sqlite3` module is too old:

```
import sqlite3
print sqlite3.version          # 2.6.0
print sqlite3.sqlite_version   # 3.8.2
```

(On another machine where `sqlite3.sqlite_version` is 3.8.7.x the extension loads fine).

I tried:

```
pip install --upgrade pysqlite
```

but it's still the same: `sqlite3.sqlite_version` stays 3.8.2.

**How to upgrade the Python sqlite3 module (which is built-in in the standard library)?**

Comment: Sidenote: I already tried this (specific for Mac), and tried to adapt it without any success: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26345972/1422096

Comment: Is it a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49053285/2072035)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right in thinking that the version of `sqlite3` causes the problem. `sqlite_malloc64` was introduced with [release 3.8.7](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_7.html).

Instead of trying to upgrade the Python `sqlite3` module which may end up breaking your Python installation, I would suggest compiling the version of `spellfix.c` included with version 3.8.2.

You can find the source here: https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/27392118/SQLite-27392118.tar.gz

From there you can build the amalgamation with:

```
sh configure
make sqlite3.c
```

You will have `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3ext.h` in the `tsrc` folder. Then compile the `spellfix.c` extension with:

```
gcc -g -fPIC -shared spellfix.c -I ../../tsrc -o spellfix.dll
```

And you should get a compatible `spellfix.dll` that runs with your version of sqlite3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Isn't there 2 links similar to  https://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-src-3110100.zip and https://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-amalgamation-3110100.zip that I could use? So I could reuse directly this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815419/1422096

Comment: I have been looking for them but I was only able to find the source of 3.8.2. I will double-check when I have some time. Hopefully the above should get you up and running although it is not exactly answering your question on how to upgrade `sqlite3`!

Comment: Thanks a lot again! Now this [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815419/1422096) is rather complete :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a 2014 OS?

Comment: You're right, about this it's 100% my fault, and probably a bad use of *If it ain't broke, don't fix it* ;) Another real reason is that I would need another server to handle the temporary reinstall etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a manual solution (NOT RECOMMENDED, but as I didn't find backports for libsqlite3 v3.23.1 for my Linux install, I tried this, and it worked):

1. Download from https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libsqlite3-0 a newer version. Here is a direct link:

   ```
   wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-0_3.23.1-1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Decompress the .deb in a temporary folder:

   ```
   mkdir tmp
   dpkg -x libsqlite3-0_3.23.1-1_amd64.deb tmp
   ```

   or

   ```
   mkdir tmp; cd tmp; ar x ../libsqlite3-0_3.23.1-1_amd64.deb; tar xvfJ data.tar.xz; cd ..
   ```

   then

   ```
   # keep the old one in case it wouldn't work!
   mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6.old   

   # copy the new one in the right place
   cp tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
   ```
3. It should work:

   ```
   python -c "import sqlite3; print sqlite3.sqlite_version"   # 3.23.1
   ```

Disclaimer: this is a bit hack-ish, but it works.

Comment: Hack-ish indeed. I attempted this to update sqlite from 3.34 to 3.37 and ran into other version dependencies. Ultimately I decided it wasn't worth the effort. Thank you though!