# Duplicate the built-in sqlite3 module into another one, to use a newer version of the sqlite3 shared library

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I'd like to use a very recent version of the sqlite3 shared library, directly compiled from the sources from https://www.sqlite.org.

Overwriting `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so` or `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` with the new compiled library seems like a bad idea because it could break some of the OS tools - that use Python and the standard sqlite3 module and don't like a new version of this shared library.

**Question: how can I duplicate the stdlib Python module `sqlite3` into a module named `sqlite3custom` that, instead of using `/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` would use `/path/to/my/custom/sqlite.so`?**

Then I would use `import sqlite3custom` in my code with exactly the same API than `sqlite3`, and this would avoid to touch to the built-in sqlite3 module.

Benefit: we could even have both in the same code, to do comparisons:

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)        # 3.23.1
import sqlite3custom
print(sqlite3custom.sqlite_version)  # 3.36 (2021-06-18), compiled from source
```

Note: this is linked but slightly different to [Upgrade Python's sqlite3 on Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820873/upgrade-pythons-sqlite3-on-debian) and [Multiple versions of Sqlite3 for Python on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68458497/multiple-versions-of-sqlite3-for-python-on-the-same-server).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use both versions of the sqlite3 library at the same time.
But, to use the non-system library in your python code, you can just update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (put the folder that contains your version before the folder with the system version)
Depending on how exactly you interact with sqlite3, maybe you would need to update `PATH` similarly.