# How can I use the FTS5 extension with the sqlite3 python module with Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04, fts5

To test whether the FTS5 extension with the sqlite3 Python module works, I use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60245219/395857) from [Vorsprung durch Technik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42346/vorsprung-durch-technik):

```
import sqlite3     
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute("""create virtual table fts5test using fts5 (data);""") 
conn.execute("""insert into fts5test (data) 
                values ('this is a test of full-text search');""")
conn.execute("""select * from fts5test where data match 'full';""").fetchall()
```

The code works fine on Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 19.04. For example one can run it via Docker with the following python3.7 interpreter:

```
docker pull ubuntu:18.04 # This line is optional.
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 bash
apt update
apt install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt update 
apt install -y python3.7
python3.7
# use here the python code given above
```

However, if I change the Ubuntu version from 18.04 to 16.04, then the FTS5 extension doesn't work:

```
docker pull ubuntu:16.04 # This line is optional.
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:16.04 bash
apt update
apt install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt update 
apt install -y python3.7
python3.7
# use here the python code given above
```

The python code will crash:

```
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute("""create virtual table fts5test using fts5 (data);""")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such module: fts5
```

How can I use the FTS5 extension with the sqlite3 Python module with Python 3.7 on Ubuntu **16.04**?

Answer (score 2):

These two articles ([Force Python to forego native sqlite3 and use the (installed) latest sqlite3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver/22231194) and http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-the-sqlite-json1-and-fts5-extensions-with-python/) could be a solution to the issue.

Try these steps:

1. Download the SQLite source code and build it with FTS5 enabled.

   ```
   $ wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
   $ tar xvzf sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz
   $ cd sqlite-autoconf-3310100
   $ CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5" ./configure
   $ make sqlite3.c
   ```
2. Before you move on, you may want to activate your virtual environment.

   ```
   $ source <path to Python3.7 virtual environment>/bin/activate
   (python37env) $
   ```
3. The author of this article (http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-the-sqlite-json1-and-fts5-extensions-with-python/) took SQLite3 DB-API 2.0 driver from Python 3 as a separate package ([enter link description here](https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3)). So you can use it to replace the original driver.

   ```
   (python37env) $ wget https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3/archive/0.4.2.tar.gz
   (python37env) $ tar xvzf 0.4.2.tar.gz
   (python37env) $ cd pysqlite3-0.4.2
   (python37env) $ cp <path to sqlite-autoconf-3310100>/sqlite3.h .
   (python37env) $ cp <path to sqlite-autoconf-3310100>/sqlite3.c .
   (python37env) $ python setup.py build_static build
   (python37env) $ python setup.py install
   ```

   Now, the seperate pysqlite module should be installed onto your virtual environment.
4. Test it. Instead of using `import sqlite3` to import the pysqlite3 module, use `from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3`. This will import the SQLite3 DB-API 2.0 driver from the custom pysqlite module. And your test code will be like the following:

   ```
   # import sqlite3
   from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3

   conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
   conn.execute("""create virtual table fts5test using fts5 (data);""")
   conn.execute("""insert into fts5test (data)
                   values ('this is a test of full-text search');""")
   conn.execute("""select * from fts5test where data match 'full';""").fetchall()
   ```

This method works on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM with Python 3.7.3.