# How can I resolve fts5 error after I upgraded Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail, fts5

I have upgraded my Wagtail installation to 2.15.1 with Django 3.1.13

When I run *manage.py migrate* I get an error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such module: fts5

I have searched but cannot find any solutions to this problem

Can someone please help?

This is the code that running in *django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py* when the error occurs

```
class SQLiteCursorWrapper(Database.Cursor):
    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
```

it fails on the line

```
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
```

the last 3 values of *query* are

```
 CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE wagtailsearch_indexentry_fts USING fts5(autocomplete, body, title)
 PRAGMA foreign_key_check
 PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

The failure happens on the last of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in wagtail

I deleted the *migrations* folder from the site wagtail package and ran *makemigrations* and *migrate*. It now works

Comment: This is definitely not recommended. It will make it incredibly difficult to upgrade to future Wagtail versions, because the migrations you generated and applied won't match the ones shipped with the next release of Wagtail.

Answer (score 0):

**This was a compatibility issue with versions of sqlite that don't provide the `fts5` extension, and has now been fixed in [Wagtail 2.15.2](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.15.2.html).**

(Old information, kept for reference:)

This is an open Wagtail issue, currently being worked on at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/7798.

For now, you'll need to ensure that the version of sqlite installed on your system comes with the `fts5` extension. For Mac and Windows, this is likely to be bundled with the Python installer, so this won't be an issue. For Linux, it depends on the distribution - Ubuntu 18.04 has it, 16.04 doesn't. See [How can I use the FTS5 extension with the sqlite3 python module with Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246821/how-can-i-use-the-fts5-extension-with-the-sqlite3-python-module-with-python-3-7) for details of how to upgrade.